# AWS IAM Policy Simulator: how to return true if there is at least one region where action is allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying to use the AWS IAM Policy simulator however I can't figure out one thing, I didn't find a clear answer [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html).

When I simulate a policy:

```
{
"Version": "2010-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "MyCoolID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }]}
```

if I don't specify a region in the **Resource** field, is the simulator going to check all the regions? and if there is only one region where I can't **ec2:CreateTags**, then the simulator will fail? I will get **Implicit Deny** even though in most of the regions I can create the tags?

If so, how do I simulate something like "return true if there is at least one region where you can ec2**:CreateTags**"

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified region condition in the policy then same can be simulated by setting region name in  Global settings and then run the simulation. it will evaluate access only for that particular region
[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer the question:
how to return true if there is at least one region

Comment: you specifically have to set the region name in global settings otherwise it will return deny. simulator doesn't list the region specifically where it is failing.
you can use api calls to do the same and provide region code as input.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-principal-policy.html

Answer (score 0):

if I don't specify a region then simulator is going to check all the regions